# Combine null safety and assertNotNull

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

In test we usually have `assertNotNull`, but it does not perform smart cast from a nullable type to a non-nullable. I have to write something like this:

```
if (test == null) {
    Assert.fail("")
    return
}
```

Is it a workaround to perform smart cast only with `assertNotNull` call? How do you deal with it?

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example of unit test that you'd like to improve? I find it easier to use `!!.otherProperty`  to assert that the receiver should not be null.

Comment: @miensol, with `!!.otherProperty` you get an NPE, and the test result will be an error, not a failed assertion. Not a big deal though.

Comment: Force-unwrapping properties is unnecessary in tests written in Kotlin. See my answer in this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64891834/1071320) which shows how to use the `kotlin-test` library's `assertNotNull` method to remove the need to force unwrap.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately, the bodies of the functions that you call, including inline functions, are not used for smart casts and nullability inference.

There's not much in your code that can be improved, and I would only suggest one thing: you can use [the Elvis operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator) with a [`Nothing`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-nothing.html#nothing) function for those assertion statements. The control flow analysis takes into account the branches resulting into `Nothing` and infers nullability from that:

```
fun failOnNull(): Nothing = throw AssertionError("Value should not be null")
```

```
val test: Foo? = foo()

test ?: failOnNull()
// `test` is not-null after that
```

<sup>This can be written without a function as well: `test ?: throw AssertionError("...")`, because a `throw` expression also has type `Nothing`.</sup>

---

Speaking of a more general case of failing an assertion, one might use a `fail(...): Nothing` function, which provides a bonus hint for the control flow analysis as well. The JUnit `Assert.fail(...)` is not a `Nothing` function, but you can find one in the [`kotlin-test-junit`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-test-junit) module or write your own one.

```
test as? SomeType ?: fail("`test` should be an instance of SomeType")
// smart cast works here, `test` is `SomeType`
```

Comment: You can also do `test ?: fail("...")`

Comment: @mfulton26, but the JUnit `Assert.fail()` is not a `Nothing` function, therefore there will be no nullability inference from this statement. Or is there a Kotlin testing library shipped with a `fail(): Nothing`  function?

Comment: `kotlin.test.fail` from `kotlin-test` (transitive dependency of `kotlin-test-junit`). I suppose the SO may not be using `kotlin-test` though so that is a good point.

Answer (score 7):

The [kotlin.test](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/kotlin.test/index.html) library comes with an easy solution for this:

`kotlin.test.assertNotNull()`

Because this function implements Kotlin contracts it supports smart casting:

`contract { returns() implies (actual != null) }`

**Example:**

```
    fun Foo?.assertBar() {
        assertNotNull(this)
        assertEquals(this.bar, 0)
    }
```

*Just make sure to use the right `assertNotNull` import (`import kotlin.test.assertNotNull`)!*

If you don't already use the `kotlin.test` library, add it to your project:

`group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', name: 'kotlin-test', version: '1.3.11`

Answer (score 0):

Big thank you to @Rolf for pointing me to the [assertNotNull](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/kotlin.test/kotlin.test/assert-not-null.html) method offered by the [kotlin-test](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/kotlin.test/) library in his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54309928/1071320).

I just want to add and point out that this method has a non-null return type (i.e. it returns the nullable object that is passed into it as a non-null object). So if you are force unwrapping properties in your test, you can move away from this and improve your tests as follows:

```
val myProperty = assertNotNull(myObject?.myProperty)
assertEquals("Foo", myProperty.someOtherProperty)
```